# How to get only seller sent messages from ebay GetMyMessages API?

Tags: php, ebay-api, trading

I have seller and buyer messages through Ebay GetMymessages API.

But I want only seller sent messages.

How to get only seller send messages separate from Ebay API?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for get seller message.
Just i used the below api.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetMemberMessagesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
  <eBayAuthToken>***</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <DisplayToPublic>false</DisplayToPublic>
  <MailMessageType>AskSellerQuestion</MailMessageType>
  <MessageStatus>CustomCode</MessageStatus>
  <StartCreationTime>2017-04-10T00:00:00.000Z</StartCreationTime>
  <EndCreationTime>2017-04-11T00:00:00.000Z</EndCreationTime>
   <Pagination>
    <EntriesPerPage>100</EntriesPerPage>
    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
  </Pagination>
```

Comment: i'm have a problm where i dont get message. can you help. I get welcome to ebay message

Comment: This code for only seller reply message.what messages you want?seller or buyer.

Comment: any message at all. i got it working. turned out to be sandbox url and credentials werent working, so used production and works now